# Issues with using a logitech streamcam, system unstable

Tags: usb, kernel, 20.04

I connected my Logitech Streamcam to my Ubuntu 20.04.1 installation. After minutes of uptime I get extreme slowdowns and the system gets very laggy. After a reboot everything is fine.

Furthermore I use a Focusrite USB Audio Interface, connected via USB as well, which might be related to this issue.

When disconnecting the Streamcam before booting, the system runs fine.

These are the logs related to the failure:

```
kernel: usb 2-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
kernel: usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
kernel: usb 2-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
kernel: usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1668]: (II) config/udev: removing device Logitech StreamCam
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1668]: (**) Option "fd" "58"
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1668]: (II) event21 - Logitech StreamCam: device removed
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1113]: (II) config/udev: removing device Logitech StreamCam
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1113]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1113]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:85
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1668]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1668]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:85
gsd-media-keys[1428]: Unable to get default source
gsd-media-keys[1977]: Unable to get default source
kernel: usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
kernel: usb 2-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
kernel: usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
kernel: usb 2-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
kernel: usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
kernel: usb 2-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
kernel: usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
kernel: usb 1-2.4: 2:1: usb_set_interface failed (-110)
...
```

This might be related to [this](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203419). But I am not sure on how to fix it, if it is even fixable or if it is a bug in the kernel.

```
kernel: usb 1-2.4: 2:1: usb_set_interface failed (-110)
pulseaudio[1577]: Failed to set hardware parameters: Input/output error
```

keeps repeating forever, and the streamcam is no longer detectable. (And the system unusable).

I don't need the audio to be working on the streamcam, just the camera itself has to work.

Comment: I have a similar problem except my system doesn't show the camera at all. I'll have to reboot and sometimes it comes up then but not all the time. It's very unstable. I'm also using a USB 3.0 PCI card but I don't think that's the issue because another computer I have with the same OS also has this issue and it has integrated USB-C ports.

Comment: Same problem on nixos, arch, and ubuntu. On different machines too. Likely a kernel problem.